# How to create a superimposed bubble chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bubble-chart

I am trying to create a bubble map in python. My dataset looks like this.

```
Year   (Total students)  (Number Passed)
-----------------------------------------
2011       (500)              (250)
2012       (350)              (150)
2013       (348)              (100)
```

Basically what I want to do is create a bubble chart to superimpose the number of students passed each year on the total number of students. The values would be the size of the bubble chart. How can I achieve this using python or matlab?

**edited:**

The actual dataset has 17 rows and 3 columns.

I used the code as suggested and this is what I get.
[image: Result of my plot using the suggested code]

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: In what format do you have this dataset? excel, csv, text, pandas dataframe, numpy array?

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266060/how-to-do-a-nested-proportional-area-chart-circles

Comment: @abhilb the dataset is in csv format

Comment: @DizietAsahi not exactly. So far my Data set with 3 years for example, I would have 3 bubble plots superimposed on each other where the bigger circle would be the total number of students and the smaller circle which will be superimposed on the bigger one would be the proportion of students who passed. And I want each year side by side in same plot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in a DataFrame, you could do something like the following:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
s = len(df.index)
plt.scatter(df["Year"], np.ones(s), s=df["Total Students"]*20, alpha=0.6)
plt.scatter(df["Year"], np.ones(s), s=df["Number Passed"]*20, alpha=0.4)

plt.yticks([])
plt.xticks(df["Year"])

plt.show()
```

Giving:

[image]

But I'm unsure if this is the best visualisation for your data, or, indeed, what your question asks for.

Comment: answered pretty much at the same time. Great mind think alike ;) +1

Comment: Thanks. Although my plot still shows a blank rectangle. I attached the picture to my question. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Just change the scaling of the values. In mine I've multiplied by 20 - in yours you might need to divide. The line to change is `s=df["Total Students"]*20`.

Comment: @Steminist Looking at the size of your posted data, you probably need to do something like `s=df["Total Students"]*1e-4`

Answer (score 1):

```
d = """Year   Total      Passed
2011       9e6              4e6
2012       10e6              3e6
2013       11e6              2e6"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\\s+', header=0)

scale = 1e-3
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['Year'], [0]*len(df['Year']), s=scale*df['Total'], label='Total')
ax.scatter(df['Year'], [0]*len(df['Year']), s=scale*df['Passed'], label='Passed')
ax.set_xticks(df['Year'])
ax.set_xticklabels(df['Year'])
ax.margins(x=0.25)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to get the exact plot. @Diziet Asahi.

Comment: Your range of data is much larger than in your original question. You'll have the change the scaling of your sizes, i.e. change the value `scale` in `s=scale*df['Total_vacc']` until you have an appropriate bubble size

Comment: Changing the scale hasn't changed anything for me. How large can it be? What do you suggest.

Comment: I've edited my answer with values that are on the same order of magnitude as yours. I had to use a `scale` of 1e-3 to get decently sized bubbles